# C# Designed doesn't recognize custom event in custom user control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, designer

I'm having trouble with VS2012 designer.  I have a user control that I designed and in it is a text box (among other things) where the user is meant to enter an IPv4, IPv6, or DNS.  I needed to validate that text as valid (TextChanged event) report back to the main program.  Consider the following code:

```
private bool addressError;

public EventHandler ErrorChanged;

public bool Error
{
    get
    {
       return addressError;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.Error != value)
        { 
            addressError = value;
            OnErrorChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void OnErrorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ErrorChanged != null)
    {
        ErrorChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Then I add the event handler to the main program designer (control name is "Com"):

```
this.Com.ErrorChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Com_ErrorChanged);
```

The problem I have is that although the code works exactly as I wanted it to, the designer thinks there is no `ErrorChanged` event.  The exact message it reports is

> *"The type 'ModbusCom.Communications' has no event named
>   'ErrorChanged'."*

I can ignore the error and the designer displays the form ok. I can run the program and everything is fine, but it's a bit annoying to have to keep telling it to ignore the problem.  Is there anything I can do to resolve this?  Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you actually trying to communicate over Modbus? (I'm just wondering)

Comment: Yes, I am.  Modbus RTU over TCP/IP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't declaring it as an event

Change:

```
public EventHandler ErrorChanged;
```

into:

```
public event EventHandler ErrorChanged;
```

Comment: Daniel is correct. What you are doing, by not using the event keyword, is creating an instance of the EventHandler delegate that is a public field. This would work, pretty much, the same way in C# code, but it would allow you to override all event handlers that are subscribing to it if you don't use += or -= to subscribe or unsubscribe. The event keyword only allows you to add (+=) or remove (-=) on the event itself.